# Greeting in cover letter to journal with 6 editors

Tags: publications

I am in the process of submitting a paper to a journal and they require a cover letter to be attached to the submission. There are multiple guides for this online from several publishers, [including Springer](https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/authorandreviewertutorials/submitting-to-a-journal-and-peer-review/cover-letters/10285574). The Springer guide suggests that:

> If known, address the editor who will be assessing your manuscript by their name. Include the date of submission and the journal you are submitting to.

The journal of my choice has six editors with no one being more senior as far as I can tell from the website information. Looking at the publication lists there are two primary candidates, editors A and B, for handling the paper (or that is my guess).

What do I use for a greeting in my cover letter?

(NB: I'm not asking about the content of such a letter and searching for `is:question cover letter [publications]` gave me nothing of interest, so I don't think it's a duplicate like other recent cover letter questions have been.)

Comment: I think this probably doesn't fall under the "if known" clause, since you don't know which editor should handle it...

Comment: @nengel I agree, so then do I just go with a generic "To whom it may concern"? It seems a little detached so I'm wondering if there are other options.

Comment: How about "Dear Editor(s)"? (I always have trouble with "dear" but I believe in English it's ok to address strangers this way...)

Comment: @hejseb "To whom it may concern" is definitely antiquated. Why not go with the classic "Dear Sir or Madam"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you don't know for sure which of the six editors of the journal will handle the submission, a generic salutation seems most appropriate.

I would go with "Dear Editors", or "Dear Editors of Journal X".